# check if asp:TextBox has focus in Asp.net4 (C#)

Tags: c#, asp.net, textbox, focus, textarea

i'm building a little Chat module like the Facebook one.
here is a little fieldset in my default.aspx file:

```
<form>
    <`asp:TextBox` ID="InstantMessageContent" runat="server" onkeypress="return EnterEvent(event)" >
    </asp:TextBox>
</form>
```

In my C# code behind file i want to check if textbox has focus to read past user message. 
i try something like this but VS2012 underlined this "**.Focused**" as unknown:

```
if (InstantMessageContent.Focused==true)
  {
      changeUnreadStatusMessageToRead(Person1, Person2);
  }
```

Can someone help me with this.  I googled it a lot but all answer i found isn't working for me.

Comment: try : ``if(InstantMessageContent.isFocused)``

Comment: I already try it InstantMessageContent.isFocused. but it's not working !. Thanks for try.

Answer (score 0):

You can not get the properties in server side to identify whether a text box is focused or not. Instead use client side script. On click or on focus event write a Java script function that triggers server side method. To do this you must add script manager to your page. Also decorate your method with web method.

ASPX:-

```
<form id="form1" runat="server" name="form1">
     <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server" EnablePageMethods="true"/>
         <div>
           <asp:TextBox ID="txtTest" runat="server"  onclick="javascript:PageMethods.ChangeUnreadStatusMessageToRead()"></asp:TextBox>
          </div>
  </form>
```

CS:-

```
[System.Web.Services.WebMethod]
public static void ChangeUnreadStatusMessageToRead()
{

}
```